# Can you pass your own weights to skimage.color.rgb2gray?

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

The [documentation page](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#rgb2gray) for `skimage.color.rgb2gray` says:

> The weights used in this conversion are calibrated for contemporary CRT phosphors:
>
> `Y = 0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B`

Suppose I want to use my own weights such that `Y = Wr * R + Wg * G + Wb * B`. Is there a way of passing an array like `[Wr, Wg, Wb]` to `rgb2gray` so it uses that instead?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no way of doing that, but since the channels are the last axis on the array, it's actually easy to do this with matrix multiplication:

```
Y = image @ [Wr, Wg, Wb]
```

So you could very easily write your own (or use this one-liner directly).

(Note: in Python 3.4 or earlier, you would instead use `np.dot(image, [Wr, Wg, Wb])`.)

Comment: This seems to create a problem when I attempt to run `color.label2rgb(some_labels, Y)` - the overlay shows up as noise, even though `some_labels` is correct.

Comment: Are your variables Wr, Wg, Wb floating point numbers?  If so, and you are still seeing problems, please most a minimal working example, so that we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt I'll try to add an MWE.

Comment: @Wassinger, I presume your image is a uint8 image in [0, 255]. Divide by 255 to get a float image in [0, 1], then try again. Alternatively, use `Y = np.round(image @ [Wr, Wg, Wb]).astype(np.uint8)`. See http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html